# Apache NiFi EvaluateJson Path starts with $ (dollar sign)

Tags: apache-nifi

How would I manage to set the extraction path of a node that is names $?

I got this JSON and I have tried to escape it like $$ but I get nothing.

```
{
"Name" : "Bla",
"$" : "A"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$['$']` I guess

Comment: that's it !! what is the logic there ? i mean i could not find anything in the exp language doco! Please put is as answer to mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [jsonpath expressions](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2)

it's possible to access keys with dot-notation or bracket-notation

bracket–notation should allow you to access the keys with non-word chars like `.`, `$`, etc.

assume you have json:

```
{
  "the.name": "boo",
  "$": "foo"
}
```

in this case to access key "the.name" you have to use brackets-notation:

```
$['the.name']
```

the same idea with `"$"` key:

```
$['$']
```

Comment: great reference Thx